# Has the pro-Russia president of Moldova taken any concrete steps toward abandoning Moldova's Association Agreement with the EU?

Tags: european-union, international-relations, russian-federation, moldova

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moldova%E2%80%93European_Union_Association_Agreement):

> On 1 July 2016, the Association Agreement (AA) between the European Union and the Republic of Moldova fully came into force, following ratification by all 31 signatories. [...]
>
> Igor Dodon, who was elected President of Moldova in November 2016, campaigned on holding a referendum on cancelling the agreement in favour of joining the [Russia-led] Eurasian Economic Union.

Has Moldova done anything concrete since then toward this realignment?

Answer (score 1):

He did [sign](https://www.rferl.org/a/moldova-dodon-signs-memorandum-on-cooperation-with-eurasian-economic-union/28408025.html) a memorandum of cooperation with the Eurasian Economic Union (EES) in 2017. I'm not sure if this affects their practical commitments to the EU AA though, but surely was a more concrete political message.

> Moldovan Prime Minister Pavel Filip harshly criticized the signing of the memorandum, saying that it is aimed to undermine efforts to forge closer ties with the European Union.
>
> Dodon "is trying to continue his personal war against the Association Agreement," Filip told reporters on April 3, referring to a Moldova-EU treaty that came to force in July 2016. [...]
>
> Filip said last week that memorandum would have "no legal effect" and that the former Soviet republic's government "will not finance any measures undertaken under this document."

I'll accept a more complete answer if he's taken steps to get Moldova out of the EU AA, or he just hopes to nullify it in practice. Since the pro-EU opposition apparently held the majority in parliament, Dodon's play appears to have been limited.